# evitar recargar páginas

Tags: css, script

Buen día, tengo un problema, tengo una página web la cual en su responsividad esta un button toggle (el clásico botón de las barras) para abrir el menú en dispositivos móviles, pero al momento de presionar el button si inicia a abir el menú pero al mismo tiempo se recarga la página lo cual me lo vuelve a quitar, quisiera saber como hago para evitar que se recargue la página, cabe recalcar que me funcionaba al principio :( jaja y no se como es que ahora sucede esto envío un script del toggle si sirve de algo

```
 <body>
    <header class="header">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <nav class="header_menu">
                <a title="CLINIKMED" href=""><img src="imgs/logo.jpg" id="Logo" alt="CLINIKMED"></a>
                <button class="nav-toggle" aria-label="abrir menú"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></button>
                <ul class="nav-menu">
                    <li>
                         <button type="submit" name="rute" value="" ><b>INICIO</b></button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button type="submit" name="rute" value="" ><b>PACIENES</b></button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <b class="tituloshead">MEDICOS</b>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><button type="submit" name="rute" value="Forms/InsertMedicos.php" ><b>AGREGAR</b></button></li>
                            <li><button type="submit" name="rute" value="Forms/ConsultaMedicos.php" ><b>CONSULTAR</b></button></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button type="submit" name="rute" value="" ><b>PATOLOGIA</b></button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button type="submit" name="rute" value="" ><b>RECETAS</b></button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button type="submit" name="rute" value="" ><b>PRESENTACIONES</b></button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button type="submit" name="rute" value="" ><b>CONSULTAS</b></button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="cerrar-sesion">
                        <a href="../includes/logout.php">
                            <b>CERRAR SESION</b>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </form>
    </header>
</body>

<script defer>
    const button = document.querySelector(".nav-toggle")
    const menu = document.querySelector(".nav-menu")

    button.addEventListener("click", () =>{
        menu.classList.toggle("header_menu_visible")
    })
</script>



<?php 

if (isset($_POST['rute'])) {
    
    $_SESSION['rute']=$_POST['rute'];

} 

?>
```

Comment: Muestra el HTML también para ser mas preciso en la respuesta, lo primero que se me ocurre es que tienes la etiqueta como un link, pero había que ver el panorama completo.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: @KairoBarillas
muchas gracias por tu respuesta, actualizaré la pregunta con el html incluido para aclaraciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es el siguiente:

```
<button class="nav-toggle" aria-label="abrir menú"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></button>
```

Debido a que ese botón esta dentro de un `<form>` lo cual interpreta que es el botón de envío del formulario, la solución sería añadir la propiedad type a **button** para que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
<button type="button" class="nav-toggle" aria-label="abrir menú"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></button>
```

Con eso bastaría para que no haga el efecto de **recargar**.

Espero te sirva esta respuesta.

Comment: UUUUUFFF MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS ENSERIO, SOLUCINADO

Comment: Ha sido un gusto, no olvides marcar la respuesta como la solución. Saludos.